# How do I use Groovy / idea plugin to manipulate intelliJ IDEA XML?

Tags: xml, gradle, groovy

I'm new to Groovy and Gradle. I don't normally do a lot with XML either. 
Problem I've got is that our integration tests aren't marked as test sources which is causing trouble with our build. As far as I can tell, they are done correctly in Gradle. OK, now some code context. This is an example of one of our problematic *.iml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id=":project:projects:chicken:integrationTest" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../project/projects/chicken" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../.." external.system.id="GRADLE" external.system.module.group="eas.project.ouboundnmanagement-project" external.system.module.type="sourceSet" external.system.module.version="6.8.0-SNAPSHOT" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../project/projects/chicken/build/classes/it" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../project/projects/chicken/src/integrationTest">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../project/projects/chicken/src/integrationTest/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../project/projects/chicken/src/integrationTest/resources" type="java-resource" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../project/projects/chicken/src/it">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../project/projects/chicken/src/it/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../project/projects/chicken/src/it/resources" type="java-resource" />
...
```

For some reason, IntelliJ IDE insists on the extra content root. It has something to do with the fact that the task name is `integrationTest` and yet in all other cases we call it `it`. For example the source directory is `src/it/java`. So that needs removing. Also, for the one that is correct, we need to change `isTestSource` to `true` and I think we also need to change `type="java-resource"` to `type="test-resource"` or perhaps `type="java-test-resource"`.

So far I've tried:

```
idea {
    module {
        iml {
            withXml { xmlProvider ->                 // Get root node.
                def moduleNode = xmlProvider.asNode()
                def contents = moduleNode.findAll { node -> node.name == 'content' }
                println "####### $contents"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above prints `#########[]` so not very helpful or informative.

There might be better approaches but one possibility would be to get a collection of all `<content...>` nodes. Iterate over it and remove the one for whom the URL attribute ends with `'integrationTest'` Also for any that have a URL that ends with `it`, retrieve `sourceFolder` elements and set the attributes `isTestSource` and `type` respectively.

Problem is that I can't figure out what calls to make to get this to happen. Doesn't help that the IDE often doesn't tell me what the possible calls are in a drop down, like it usually does.

[UPDATE] I've got code now that fixes the problem but IntellJ is not recognizing the changed *.iml's. Before the update to 2016.1.3 it was.

So my source sets for integration testing now look like"

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/it/java')
            output.classesDir   = "$buildDir/classes/it"
        }

        def resourceDir = file('src/it/resources')
        if (resourceDir.exists()) {
            resources.srcDir resourceDir
            output.resourcesDir = "$buildDir/resources/it"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use the gradle plugin in idea to create the idea project, source and test source directories should be marked correctly as long as they are added to the sourceSets in build.gradle.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the case. Not for us anyway.

Comment: Anyway, we are talking about integration tests.

Comment: First, are you using the latest version of Idea? Second, why don't you show us your `build.gradle`? Maybe we'll be able to help you fix the problem without questionable xml manipulations.

Comment: @Roman Because I suspect the problem originates in something I already know they won't give me scope to fix. Specifically that somewhere in the deep, dark, vast forest of this build there are backward dependencies between integrationTest and test which are causing issues. When I get a chance, I'm going to prove this with a small experimental build.  In a nutshell what's expected is that what ever screw-ups in build architecture were possible in Maven are possible in Gradle so we don't have to fix anything.

Comment: I'll post the imported file for integration testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work if you link to Gradle. Further, there's a bug that prevents integration tests from being properly marked. Please vote for it.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151925

Comment: It looks like maybe they've fixed it. :-)